# c++ async only running on one core?

Tags: c++, multithreading, chess

I'm currently attempting to implement lazy SMP for my chess engine, which involves running the search algorithm on different cores (as out of sync as possible) and (hopefully) reaping the benefits of a shared hash table. It still only runs on one core though. Code below (I've removed the parts that aren't relevant) .

Iterative deepening loop:

```
for( distance; distance <= depth && IDTimeS < endTime; ) {

    positionCount = 0;
    clock_t currentTime = clock();

    if( currentTime >= endTime ) {
        distance - 1;
        break;
    }      

    //multi threading testing
    int val = multi( distance, alpha, beta, false, currentTime, timeLimmit, currentDepth +1, true, z0, z1, z2 );

    //increment distance to travel (same as depth at max depth)
    distance++;
}
```

Multi-threading function:

```
int Ai_Logic::multi(
    int distance,
    int alpha,
    int beta,
    bool isWhite,
    long currentTime,
    long timeLimmit,
    int currentDepth,
    bool allowNull,
    ZobristH *z0,
    ZobristH *z1,
    ZobristH *z2
)
{
    auto f1 = std::async( std::launch::async, &Ai_Logic::alphaBeta, this, distance, alpha, beta, isWhite, currentTime, timeLimmit, currentDepth, allowNull, BB0, z0 );
    auto f2 = std::async( std::launch::async, &Ai_Logic::alphaBeta, this, distance-1, alpha, beta, isWhite, currentTime, timeLimmit, currentDepth, allowNull, BB1, z1 );
    auto f3 = std::async( std::launch::async, &Ai_Logic::alphaBeta, this, distance+1, alpha, beta, isWhite, currentTime, timeLimmit, currentDepth, allowNull, BB2, z2 );

    auto val  = f1.get();
    auto val2 = f2.get();
    auto val3 = f3.get();

    return val;
}
```

Is there an obvious reason that i'm missing why it's still only using one core?

Comment: how do you know its only using one thread?

Comment: processor usage? Unless i totally misunderstand. Is there a different way to force it to split among cores?

Comment: watching processor usage is a poor indicator of thread creation, especially if they complete quickly.

Comment: I've forced them to take forever by increasing the depth of the search. Total cpu usage never goes over 30% for the search. Which is the same as a normal non-multi-threaded search. I have a quad core so that's about consistent with just using one core. Any Ideas on how I can force it to use all the cores?

Comment: btw, do you know what is the difference between asynchronous and parallel execution? AFAIK `std::async` does not imply parallelism.

Comment: That could be it, I'm only using async because another post I found said it's basically std::thread but returns a value. So am I looking for a way to force the thread to a given core?

Comment: After reading this [link](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-8-futures-and-promises.html) It looks like std::asyc when coupled with std::launch::async should be forcing parallel processing.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser, that is true but not in this case. std::async should force a new thread in this case.

Comment: @MaxC, nothing you've shown is demonstrating that only one thread is being used. You should print the thread ID in the threaded function (using `std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;` with a mutex wrapping the call). If all the IDs are the same, you have a single thread. As others have said, judging resource usage is a bad indicator of thread creation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what is at least a work around the problem I was having. So long as the threads are created before the iterative deepening loop and joined after I'm definitely getting multi-core usage.

```
std::thread t0(&Ai_Logic::alphaBeta, this, depth+1, alpha, beta, false, 0, timeLimmit, currentDepth, true, BB0, z0);
std::thread t1(&Ai_Logic::alphaBeta, this, depth-1, alpha, beta, false, 0, timeLimmit, currentDepth, true, BB1, z1);

for( distance; distance <= depth && IDTimeS < endTime; ) {

positionCount = 0;
clock_t currentTime = clock();

if( currentTime >= endTime ) {
    distance - 1;
    break;
}      

//normal alpha beta call
int val = alphaBeta(distance, alpha, beta, false, currentTime, timeLimmit, currentDepth +1, true, newBoard, mZobrist);


//increment distance to travel (same as depth at max depth)
distance++;
}

t0.join();
t1.join();
```